# How to get MathML to render properly when switching views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax, mathml

When my web page initially loads, any MathML content that it contains will render as expected. However, once I navigate to another view that also contains MathML content, the new content does not render correctly.

If I navigate back to the initial view, the original content that rendered correctly no longer does so. I'm using the MathJax library with AngularJS.

How do I get the MathML to always render correctly?

Example code found here: https://github.com/JustCant/mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this issue.

I created the following controller and added it to my "app" module:

```
.controller("mainCtrl", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$watch(function() {
   MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
   return true;
  });
}]);
```

The following documentation explains in greater detail:
http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html